# Random Forest Regression MAE

Tags: python, machine-learning, scikit-learn, regression, random-forest

I'm trying to create a random forest regression model to predict a continuous variable with the following characteristics (after log-transformation):

count    2868.000000
mean        4.566630
std         1.233496
min        -0.356675
25%         3.745966
50%         4.604670
75%         5.452325
max         8.141889

The best result I get in terms of negative mean absolute error is -0.64. How should I evaluate this result? Is it good/decent/bad?

Thank you very much.

Answer (score -1):

here is a link to the docs [docs](https://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.metrics.mean_absolute_error.html)

the simple answer to your question is yes it is a good to have a -0.64 NMAE.

NMAE is the opposite of MAE but you can basically remove the minus and treat it as a normal MAE. so that means if you have a high MAE  that means the NMAE is also high and that is not a good result but a low MAE can be seen as low NMAE and that's considered a good result of course depending on what you want to have.